# SUPERSET generate SQL template from a loop in python

Tags: python, sql, jinja2, apache-superset

I want to create a simple sql using jinja templating in superset but this doesn't work.
input

```
{{n}} -- this is where we set the parameter or range to use 
{% for i in range(n): %}
    {% s+=f'SELECT i\n' %}
    {% if i < n-1: %}
        {% s+='UNION ALL\n'%}
    {% end if %}
{% end for %}
```

in python the code might look like this

```
s = ""
n = 5
for i in range(5):
    s+=f'SELECT {i}\n'
    if i < n-1:
        s+='UNION ALL\n'
```

expected output

```
SELECT 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 2
UNION ALL
SELECT 3
UNION ALL
```

Help appreciated thank you!

Comment: Is the last UNION ALL in expected output a typo?

Comment: Would it be an option to put the different queries into the same df and not trying and manipulate the SQL query portion?